# how to parse the value returned by truffle ?

Tags: solidity, truffle

I need the value of string. Also, what is the significance of s , e , c .

```
truffle(development)> x.then(function(result) { 
     console.log(result[4]);});}});
    undefined
    truffle(development)> 
{ [String: '100000000000000000000'] s: 1, e: 20, c: [ 1000000 ] }
```

I am able to fetch result[4].s or result[4].e

Sorry if this is a simple question. I am very new to javascript environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is BigNumber. See [A note on big numbers in web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js).

You can convert it to string using [`toString`](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#toS) method:

```
> const n = new web3.BigNumber('1234567890');
> n.toString()
'1234567890'
> n.toString(16)
'499602d2'
```

Also it seems that your return value is somehow related to money (ether or some other tokens). In this case you may find useful functions like [`web3.fromWei`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3fromwei) and [`web3.toWei`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3towei):

```
> const n = new web3.BigNumber('100000000000000000000');
> web3.fromWei(n, 'ether').toString();
'100'
```

Comment: sure, will check out but how to separate out String in a variable. For ex:  if I want to fetch  c --> I would do console.log(result[4].c) . Similarly how to retrieve  the string value

Comment: Actually those `c`, `s` and `e` are internals of BigNumber and may be subject to change in the future. You should not rely on them in your code. it is better to use bignumber's [public API](http://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js).