# how to parse the value returned by truffle? from balanceOf()

Tags: truffle, erc-20, bignumber

My question is nearly identical to: [how to parse the value returned by truffle ?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12791/how-to-parse-the-value-returned-by-truffle)

Except that when I run:

```
bigNumberValue.toString()
```

i get

```
'[object Promise]'
```

but then if I treat as a promise and run:

```
bigNumberValue.toString().then(a=>{console.log(a)})
```

I get

```
balance1.toString(...).then is not a function
```

I am running Truffle v4.1.12 (core: 4.1.12). I am trying to get the value out of the BigNumber. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am running my code from a truffle test script. IE with the command "truffle test /path/to/my/file.js" --network ganache"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bigNumberValue` is a Promise as you state also in your question. However, the way you're handling the Promise is wrong.

This should work:

```
balance1.then(a => {
    console.log(a.toString())
})
```

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clear that I am working in a truffle test script. Your solution works perfectly in the truffle console. But when I do the same thing in a truffle test script, I get "balance0.then is not a function". I also tried balance0.get() but I get the error "balance0.get is not a function"

Comment: It seems that balance1.toString() works from the truffle test script. Here is what confuses me: if I console.log(balance1) either from the truffle console or truffle test script I get "{ s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 0 ] }". But balance.toString() works from the test script, but does not work from the console... I don't understand the difference